# Generalisation of the Swap trick

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, tensor-products

For a permutation $\pi \in S_d$, operators $A_i \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$, how can $Tr(\pi \left(  A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_d\right) )$ be simplified? $\otimes$ is the tensor product aka Kronecker product.

If $\pi$ is a d-cyclic shift then $Tr( \pi A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes  A_d ) = Tr(A_1 \cdots A_d) $ (cyclic-permutation-trick) but what if $\pi \in S_d$ does consist of multiple shorter cycles?

Comment: Please explain the notion. For example, what are $A_i$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I added informations

Comment: Alright. And what does $\pi A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_d$ mean? Does the $\pi$ act  on $A_1$ or the whole tensor product? And you really mean the tensor procuct ($\approx$ Kronecker product) here, right?

Comment: yes $\pi\in S_d$ so it acts on $d$ objects

Comment: Ah, so you want to simplify $\mathrm{Tr}(A_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes A_{\sigma(d)})$.

Comment: But we always have $\mathrm{Tr}(A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_d) = \mathrm{Tr}(A_1) \cdots \mathrm{Tr}(A_d)$, so I don't understand the problem. You can exchange the tensor factors as you like, the trace doesn't change. Is that really the question?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I want that those that are cycled are evaluated like a product inside the trace, for example for $(12) \in S_3$ $Tr((12)A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes A_3) = Tr(A_1A_2)Tr(A_3)$

Comment: I still don't get it. Your question is not interesting for the tensor product. Maybe it is for the product / composition of the operators.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg my motivation was to understand eq. 320 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.08956.pdf, where the swap trick is generalised. I am happy with any suggestions who to clearify the question.